# data & synchronization - manually sync mail. calender and contacts

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I am trying to write an app that syncs my mail and my calender with just a single click. After looking through this forum I found some good hints and wrote a short test app that takes my first google account and starts syncing.

The code is working so far but currently only the contacts were synced!

```
    AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
    Account[] acc = am.getAccountsByType("com.google");
    Account account = null;
    if (acc.length > 0) {
        account = acc[0];

        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true);
        extras.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);

        ContentResolver.requestSync(account, ContactsContract.AUTHORITY,
                extras);
    }
```

The method requestSync takes "authority" as parameter and now I use "ContactsContract.AUTHORITY" and I guess that is the reason for only synching my contacts.
My question now is, does anybody know what authority string I have to use to only sync my mail and calender?
If "null" is used as authority all three (cal, contacts and mail) get synched

```
public static void requestSync (Account account, String authority, Bundle extras)
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, it seems the the Authority for contacts is:

```
"com.android.contacts"
```

and for calander:

```
"com.android.calendar"
```

But I could not find the String for syncing Gmail...